# Different Types of Full Stack Architectures

Tags: architecture

I have built a few stacks in my time as a self-taught full-stack developer, but I think there may be a hole in my knowledge that you can hopefully fill in for me. I have built a few stacks that *all* have a core architecture like this:

- Backend in Go, interfacing with a Postgres database or doing some core logic
- RESTful API server (also written in Go) serving over HTTPS that triggers database methods/backend logic
- Frontend in JavaScript using ReactJS or some other framework. The front end makes calls to the API server (using `fetch()`) whenever data is needed/logic should be executed (on the backend).

I find that this is a pretty good, common architecture that can work in many different use cases. However, I am wondering if there is any other type of core architecture that differs from this. I have heard of GraphQL and I see how that is different than this traditional REST-like architecture, but I am wondering if there is some other type of architecture used to build web apps that does not revolve around a REST/SOAP/GraphQL API. I've heard of WebSockets, and I think that they fit into what I am asking about here, so how are they different from just calling JavaScript's `fetch()` to make calls to my REST API (or using a third-party library like `axios`.)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a listing question.

Answer (score 5):

The architecture of your application is whatever you decide it is.  The alphabet soup you've mentioned in your question is just the ones that are more well-known.  Each approach has its own features and advantages.

How websockets is different is that it's more "real-time."  It's not uncommon to have a REST architecture that is supplemented by websockets to provide things like real-time dashboards, or the "this post has been edited, click here to reload" banner you sometimes see on Stack Exchange sites.

When you create a websocket, you open a two-way communication channel.  This clearly differs from the other architectures you've mentioned, as those architectures are based on querying the endpoint to obtain some data.  It's the difference between making a telephone call each time, and leaving the line open while you talk.

Comment: So you say that the "alphabet soup" I mentioned are "well-known." What are some other, less well-known architectures that you can think of ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You're asking broadly about web app architecture, but focusing solely on client-server communication, i.e. the application layer. The style of communication doesn't really change the overall architecture pattern; these are just different data types or protocols. That's an implementation detail of an architecture, not the architectural pattern itself.

[You can find some useful primers for web app architecture patterns](https://www.redhat.com/architect/5-essential-patterns-software-architecture), but here's a quick list (and a super elementary description) of some of the most common:

- Client-server, which is what you have described
- Microservices, wherein the UI interacts with several backend servers with specialized domains
- Layered, wherein concerns in the backend (and sometimes the frontend, as with a robust Redux service, for example) are broken into different concerns-- good for testability
- Peer-to-peer, wherein clients serve as both consumers and suppliers of resources

These aren't necessarily mutually exclusive. These can all be combined in different ways based on the needs of the application.